# counting the null values along with non null values in the SQL in the single count column

Tags: sql, sqlite

My code snippet

\\

```
movie_female_cast = pd.read_sql_query(""" SELECT TRIM(MC.MID), COUNT(P.Gender),P.Gender FROM M_Cast MC
INNER JOIN Person P
ON P.PID = TRIM(MC.PID)
WHERE P.Gender IN ('Male',NULL, 'Female')

GROUP BY MC.MID 
""",conn)
\\\
```

OUTPUT-
'''

```
     TRIM(MC.MID)  COUNT(P.Gender)  Gender
0       tt0021594                8    Male
1       tt0026274               20    Male
2       tt0027256               13    Male
3       tt0028217               10    Male
4       tt0031580               44  Female
...           ...              ...     ...
3468    tt8581230                8  Female
3469    tt8698956               10    Male
3470    tt8852558               17    Male
3471    tt8932884                3    Male
3472    tt9007142                9    Male
'''
```

here in P.Gender column, there are 3 categories - Female, Male, Null. Now i want to find the movie id against which the count of all the 3 above mentioned categories, right now with above code COUNT is not actually taking the NULL values into account and returns just Male and Female categories. Can somebody please help

Comment: where p.Gender is null or p.Gender In ('Male', 'Female')

Comment: Thanks, that worked and i realised i was doing such a silly mistake when i had used this logic earlier! :)

Comment: hi - i was too quick to answer i guess, however by adding - where p.Gender is null or p.Gender In ('Male', 'Female') is still not counting the null values. it still gives me count only for the Male and Female Gender but not for the Null values

Comment: Oh you want count. Your output was leading. Then instead of count(p.Gender), just use count(*). You are already filtering for Male, Female and null.

Answer (score 0):

For count, do not specify p.Gender:

```
movie_female_cast = pd.read_sql_query(""" SELECT TRIM(MC.MID), COUNT(*),P.Gender FROM M_Cast MC
    INNER JOIN Person P
    ON P.PID = TRIM(MC.PID)
    WHERE P.Gender is NULL or p.Gender IN ('Male','Female')
    
    GROUP BY MC.MID, p.gender 
    """,conn)
```